# Lifting-Line Theory - Numerical solution for a wing with dihedral angle

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing

I'm trying to calculate lift for a wing with a dihedral angle using the Lifting-Line Theory. While using the thesis "[Non-Planar Lifting-Line Theory for Fixed and Deformable Geometries](https://soar.wichita.edu/bitstream/handle/10057/7039/t13061_Kuenn.pdf?sequence=1)" as a reference, he describes the following governing equation for a wing with dihedral:

$$\alpha(s_0) = \frac{\Gamma(s_0)}{\pi V_\infty c(s_0)}+\alpha_{L=0}(s_0)+\\ +\frac{1}{4\pi V_\infty}\int_{\frac{-b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\frac{d\Gamma / ds}{\sqrt{(y_0-y)^2+(y_0sin\phi-ysin\phi)^2}}cos(\phi-\beta)ds$$

As explained by Anderson, I know that the original LLT equation can be solved by writting the elliptic lift distribution as a Fourier series, substituting in the equation, producing matrices and solving for $A_n$:

$$\Gamma(\theta) = \Gamma_0 sin\theta = 2bV_\infty \sum_{1}^{N}A_n sin(n\theta)$$

However, I can't do the same for the equation of the dihedral, as he adds the circulation in function of the arc length of the wing. I tried manipulating the elliptic lift distribution to be in function of the arc length whilst using the thesis as reference, and arrived at:

[image: Wing representation by the thesis]

$$z(y) = y sin\phi$$
$$s = \sqrt{y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{y^2+(y sin\phi)^2} \rightarrow y = \sqrt{\frac{s^2}{1+sin^2\phi}}$$
$$\Gamma(y) = \Gamma_0\sqrt{1-(\frac{2y}{b})^2} \rightarrow \Gamma(s) = \Gamma_0 \sqrt{1-\frac{4s^2}{(1+sin^2\phi)b^2}}$$

However, I'm unsure if it would be efficient trying to transform this equation in a Fourier series, or even if my thought process is correct. Could anyone give me some tips on how to proceed? I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can we also see the thesis you refer to? There's a link to it?

Comment: @sophit Sure! Here's a link: [Non-Planar Lifting-Line Theory for Fixed and Deformable Geometries](https://soar.wichita.edu/bitstream/handle/10057/7039/t13061_Kuenn.pdf?sequence=1).
The formulations are on chapter 3.